# Как установить  Ratchet

Tags: php, ratchet

Добрый день.
Подскажите, как установить Ratchet?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[Документация!](http://socketo.me/docs/install)

Comment: Пробовал и это тоже https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XZyMJjWqJ4 .
Выводит ошибку http://prntscr.com/685z2g

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Я Вам в [комментариях](http://hashcode.ru/questions/401620#401709 писал). Кроме того, есть мнение, что Вы совершенно не умеете пользоваться [composer-ом](https://getcomposer.org/). [Автор видеоролика использует](http://youtu.be/_XZyMJjWqJ4?t=42s) этот пакетный менеджер, чтобы установить все необходимые зависимости.

Comment: Может и не правильно. Ну, насколько я понял - создаю такой же composer.json, скачиваю в одну папку composer.phar, запускаю, как в примере. Всё переписываю как в примере, но на видео на 28 секунде папки bin нет, а на 33-й есть. Отличие в этом, а потом он ссылается на неё. Просто вроде всё повторяю, а получается не то.